# Connect to Oracle database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I am working on POC where I want my project to connect to Oracle database using EF 6. Here is what I have referenced [Click Here](https://csharp.today/entity-framework-6-database-first-with-oracle/)

I am using ODP.NET Managed Driver (referenced `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` & `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` DLL from my project).

Downloaded & installed EF 6.

**Problem:**
When I am trying to add new connection "Server Explorer" of VS2017, I get an error

> ORA-12514: TNS: listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Not sure why I am getting this error as I am not using TNS. I am using EZConnect (See Image)

- Operating System: Windows 7
- .Net Framework: 4.6.2
- Visual Studio 2017

Any thoughts? What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try the following in ORacle:

```
select value from v$parameter where name='service_names'
```

Then need to verify `service_names` is valid in `tnsnames.ora`.

In windows 7, tnsnames.ora is located here:

%ORACLE_HOME%\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora

Comment: Okay, So I executed that query & I got different service name than specified in the image which is `ORCL`. I replaced it and that works. As per this http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT `tnsnames.ora` is unnecessary.